# Sql join right table multiple row to column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Sql how to join right table multiple row to column

Table Application_detail

```
Id     appl_name     status
1.        Abc.          1
2.        DEF.          1
```

Table Approve_detail

```
applicant_id.   Remark.      Approveby
      1.     Appr by village Village
      1.      Appr by dist.  District
```

I want to join like

```
Id.  Applname. Status. Village_remark. District_remark
1.   Abc.       1.      Appr by village. Appr by dist
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What happened to row #2 `DEF`?

Comment: What are the primary keys and foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you have hardcoded list of ApproveBys, you can do this:

```
SELECT    ad.Id,
          ad.appl_name AS Applname,
          ad.status,
          vil.Remark as Village_remark,
          dist.Remark as Distric_remark
FROM Application_detail ad
JOIN Approve_detail vil
ON   vil.applicant_id = ad.id
AND  vil.Approveby = 'Village'
JOIN Approve_detail dist
ON   dist.applicant_id = ad.id
AND  dist.Approveby = 'District'
```

Otherwise you need to build a dynamic SQL. Like this:

```
-- Filling in initial data
SELECT *
INTO #Application_detail
FROM
(
SELECT 1 Id, 'Abc' appl_name, 1 Status
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DEF', 1
) t

SELECT *
INTO #Approve_detail
FROM
(
SELECT 1 applicant_id, 'Appr by village' Remark, 'Village' Approveby
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Appr by dist.', 'District'
) t

-- Start of the code
SELECT DISTINCT Approveby
INTO #Approvers
FROM #Approve_detail;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SELECT NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @FROM NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SELECT = 'SELECT ad.Id, ad.appl_name AS Applname, ad.status'
SET @FROM = '
FROM #Application_detail ad'
SET @WHERE = '
WHERE ad.id IN (SELECT applicant_id FROM #Approve_detail)'

SELECT @SELECT += ', t' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR) + '.Remark AS ' + Approveby + '_remark',
        @FROM += '
LEFT JOIN #Approve_detail t' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR) + '
ON t' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR) + '.applicant_id = ad.id
AND t' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR) + '.Approveby = ''' + Approveby + ''''
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Approveby) rn, Approveby FROM #Approvers
) t

SET @SQL= @SELECT + @FROM + @WHERE;

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: This example works on SQL Server, please adjust to Oracle.

Comment: First hardcode is ok but instead of multiple join on same table how to use single join to get both village and district remark

Comment: You will need two joins. Is there anything that restricts you from using several joins?